# Read a CSV file in java and retrieve values handling all the n-cases

Tags: java, file, csv

```
name,priceperproduct,qty_sold
"Pollen's - Weeds, Weed mix 2630",72,117
Losartan Potassium,46,532
INSTANT HAND SANITIZER,65,594
"Sodium Sulfacetamide, Sulfur",45,359`
```

I have to get 3 strings from each line that corresponds to `name`, `priceperproduct` and `qty_sold` respectively.

I have to handle all the possible n-cases. What can I do?

Comment: You can produce some code, do some research, etc. Way faster that waiting for someone to write code for you. And it's also way more useful as it makes you learn.

Comment: What is a n-case? What kind of output you want to obtain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object that holds the variables name, price and quantity. You can then split each line and store each separated value in an array of the object created earlier.

Product.java

```
public class Product {

private String name;
private int price;
private int qty;

public Product(String name, int price, int qty) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.qty = qty;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public int getQty() {
    return qty;
}

public void setQty(int qty) {
    this.qty = qty;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Product{" + "name=" + name + ", price=" + price + ", qty=" + qty + '}';
}

}
```

GetProducts.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GetProducts {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    String csvFile = "products.csv"; //path to your csv file
    String line = "";
    String headerLine;
    int x = 0;

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {

          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

              if (x==0) // ignore header line
              {
                  headerLine = line;
              }
              else
              {
                // use comma as separator
                String[] split = line.split(",");

                //Some product names contain commas that are part of the name, so we split again using quotation marks
                if (line.charAt(0) == '"')
                {
                    String[] split2 = line.split("\"");
                    //here we retrieve the rest of the data after the last quotation mark
                    //careful, it will only work if there are quotation marks in the product name only
                    split = split2[split2.length - 1].split(",");
                    products.add(new Product(split2[1], Integer.parseInt(split[1]), Integer.parseInt(split[2])));
                }
                else
                {
                    //Here we just split using commas if there are no quotation marks in the product name
                    products.add(new Product(split[0], Integer.parseInt(split[1]), Integer.parseInt(split[2])));
                }
              }
              x++; // increment x;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Output all Product objects
    for (Product product : products)
    {
        System.out.println(product);
    }

    //Output products names only
    for (Product product: products)
    {
        System.out.println(product.getName());
    }
}

}
```

This will output:

[image]